# How can I animate the rotation quaternion of an object with just one driver?

Tags: python, interface, drivers

Updated Question (driving orientation instead of location)

I'd like to animate the orientation of an object using one single driver, but it seems that the UI only let's me animate each coordinate of the rotation quaternion separately. I see that the documentation says that `Context Menu --> Add Driver` has the option `All from Target (properties icon)`, but I can't manage to select more than one of the properties at once.

I would like to be able to do this via the UI first, then figure it out how to do it from Python.

Comment: Please state months of experience with Blender, Python, and Blender API.

Comment: Blender = 2 months; Python = years; Blender API = 1 month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion is to cooperate with Blender and simply use 3 drivers on the XYZ.  So far you do not have a strong case for fighting against this.   This does not appear to be a significant inconvenience and there are other issues you have yet to encounter.

If your were to state you have many objects such as 888 objects then another approach would be warranted.

You may also use Copy [Location,et cetera] Constraint to copy values from another object.

You can search [registering a function] but I would recommend against that until you state your level of experience with Blender and Python.

Comment: how about driving the orientation? In that case, one would not want to update each coordinate of a quaternion separately, but the whole quaternion at once (all four coordinates).

Comment: The comment is a change to the concept of your original question.  You may change your words of original question.  The choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I updated the question accordingly.